# How to analyze a video stream

Tags: video, stream, pixel

Is it possible to analyze a video stream on the fly?  For example, say i have a TV tuner installed and want to do some pixel testing every .5 seconds.  How would one go about doing analysis?  Would it be the same procedure if it was a video file (ie .mpg / .wma)?

Comment: Just to get some more information about your question:

1) What platform/platforms are you targeting? Does this need to be cross-platform or on a single platform?
2) What specific types ov TV tuners do you have installed?
3) What kind of pixel testing are you looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, have a look at [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)

Answer (score 0):

If it was a video file, you would have to decompress it to get the pixel information. If you wan't to do analysis at the pixel level, you basically needs to do a screenshot or a dump to disk. If you can do that, then you have access to the video frame data, and you can start to mess with it.

If you are on windows, I can't help you, but there are handsome tools where you can graphically put a filter at some point in the chain from your tv tuner to your disk.

If you are on linux, the v4l2 capture example is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's possible but it is very recommended to use special non-pc hardware